# How to show and hides nodes when you move the mouse over a node in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created three nodes (circles) based on reading some data from JSON file using D3 Javascript. Here are my code and the JSON file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<style>

.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

d3.json("input.json", function(error, graph) {
force
.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
.call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
.attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
.attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JSON file:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "group": 1
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 2
    }
]
}
```

The code works simply as follows: There is a base node that is linked to two other nodes. What I would like to do is when I move the mouse over the base node, the other two nodes that connected to the base node will be displayed. As soon as you move the mouse out of the base node, the other two nodes will hide. I am new to D3 Javascript and do not know how to code this part.

Comment: There is similar Q to this one: works with `click` event. See [d3js force layout with hide/unhide on node click misplaces nodes after expanding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537905/d3js-force-layout-with-hide-unhide-on-node-click-misplaces-nodes-after-expanding)

Comment: By the way, as you're a new user...make sure to accept whatever answer you find to be the most appropriate (click the green check). I think both answers are good.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this by attaching mouse event handlers to the nodes that set the visibility accordingly. I've taken your example and modified the data slightly so that the node that's triggering these actions has group 2 to be able to identify it.

Then all you need to do is select the other nodes based on the group and set visibility:

```
var node = svg
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag)
  .style("visibility", function (d) {
    return d.group === 1 ? "hidden" : "visible";
  })
  .on("mouseover", function (d) {
    if (d.group === 2) {
      node.filter(function (d) { return d.group === 1; })
          .style("visibility", "visible");
    }
  })
  .on("mouseout", function (d) {
    if (d.group === 2) {
      node.filter(function (d) { return d.group === 1; })
          .style("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  });
```

Complete example [here](http://vida.io/documents/fgt6oRLyNG9muHbG9).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see the links but cant see the nodes.

Comment: I thought that was what you were asking for?

Comment: I am sorry, Lars. At this moment, I can see only the paths. I moved the mouse over the paths but the nodes are not displayed. My idea was to keep the base node visible and as soon as you move the mouse over that node, the other two nodes and their links will display.

Comment: You should be able to see the center node.

Comment: I changed what you had changed on JSON file. That was the problem. Thank you very much, Lars.

Comment: It seems to me that I am more likely dealing with data more than elements themselves. For instance, you have used the data "group" in JSON file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes -- this is completely arbitrary. You could just as well introduce a new attribute "visible" or something like that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff can the lines be hidden too? I have the following code: `links.forEach(function (link) { 
        var s = link.source = nodeById.get(link.source),
            t = link.target = nodeById.get(link.target),
            i = {};
        nodes.push(i);
        links.push({ source: s, target: i }, { source: i, target: t });
        bilinks.push([s, i, t]);
    })`

Comment: @D.Ister yes, you would need to filter the links similar to how the nodes are filtered in the answer.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the complete example link is now dead